# How to remove a shortcut file in c#

Tags: c#, file, shortcut

How to remove the program icon from the Programs folder?

Answer (score 7):

To get the start menu location, use the [SpecialFolder enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx). Something like the following should get you started:

```
string startMenuDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu);
string shortcut = Path.Combine(startMenuDir, @"The Company\MyShortcut.lnk");
if (File.Exists(shortcut))
    File.Delete(shortcut);
```

If you don't know the exact file name, you could enumerate over all the files in the start menu folder using [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx) or [Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories.aspx).
You could also remove the entire folder ("The Company"), using [Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

A shortcut file is a normal file that happens to redirect (on click) the call to another file, program or directory. To remove a shortcut you can use the [File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) method.

```
File.Delete(path_to_lnk_file);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Windows explorer, the file extension for links (lnk) is never shown, even if you have disabled the *Hide extensions for known file types* feature.

So if you want to delete the 'Shortcut to foobar.exe' shortcut, you have to do

```
File.Delete("Shortcut to foobar.exe.lnk");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard file operations on shortcuts.

I believe the file extension is lnk.

Answer (score 0):

1- Be sure to get actual file link use OpenFileDialog

---

OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
                od.DereferenceLinks = false;

[use DereferenceLinks](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?549631-RESOLVED-Shortcut-path-in-VB-NET)

2 use shell lib to get all information including the path

---

[GetShortcutInfo](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2018/06/get-information-about-windows-shortcuts-in-c/)

---

### finaly usse c# file.move or delete according to the path